# Why don't the values for a single studentid add up while i execute this SQL statement even though i used Distinct?

Tags: sql, select, subquery

[image]
I have to write a query to display the studentid and the total fees paid by each student and then sort the result based on studentid in ascending order.

*I have used Distinct so that studid is displayed only once but still I don't get the expected output.*

**My code:**

```
select distinct s.studid,c.fees as total_fees from Student s join 
Registration r on s.studid=r.studid join Course c on r.courseid=c.courseid
group by s.studid,c.fees order by s.studid;
```

**My Output:**

[image]

**Expected Output:**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You join registration.
That would give you one record per student and registration,
which is what you want.
Calling distinct on it then, though, means you only get one of those records.

What you want to do is sum up those fees, group the results per student, and order by studid.

```
SELECT s.studid, SUM(c.fees) as total_fees FROM student s 
JOIN registration r ON s.studid = r.studid
JOIN course c ON r.courseid=c.courseid
GROUP BY s.studid
ORDER BY s.studid;
```

Answer (score 1):

You are querying by distinct combination of the student ID and the fees instead of **summing** the fees:

```
SELECT   s.studid, SUM(c.fees) as total_fees 
FROM     student s 
JOIN     registration r ON s.studid = r.studid
JOIN     course c ON r.courseid=c.courseid
GROUP BY s.studid
ORDER BY s.studid ASC
```